# ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'cgi'

Tags: import, tree, pycharm, nltk

I'm getting the error message "ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'cgi'" when I try to use following code in pycharm:

```
import nltk 
parser = nltk.ChartParser(grammar, trace=0)

for tree in parser.parse(sent):
    print(tree)
    tree.pretty_print(unicodelines=True)
```

What should I do to correct it?

Comment: what python version do you use? Is it 3.8?

Comment: Yes, it is 3.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have updated the `supervisor` package version into:
`supervisor==4.1.0`

https://pypi.org/project/supervisor/4.1.0/

[Fixed a Python 3.8 compatibility issue caused by the removal of cgi.escape(). Patch by Mattia Procopio.]

problem solved.

Comment: It is not working even after installing supervisor version 4.1.0 Is there any other solution to this?

Answer (score 12):

`cgi.escape()` has been removed in python 3.8. Quoting from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html),

> parse_qs, parse_qsl, and escape are removed from the cgi module. They
>   are deprecated in Python 3.2 or older. They should be imported from
>   the urllib.parse and html modules instead.

Since you are importing a third-party module, try using a lower python version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But is there any other way that doesn't need a downgrade?

Comment: I don't think so. You are getting the error because nltk has implemented `cgi.escape` in its code. Either you'll have to wait until they make nltk compatible with python 3.8 or do it yourself using nltk [source](https://github.com/nltk/nltk). Also, maybe try opening an issue there?

Answer (score 5):

You can use html.escape instead of cgi.escape.
It worked for me